# Ag grid exportDataAsExcel run export to xml instead xlsx

Tags: angular, ag-grid, export-to-excel, export-to-xml

I add context menu and reassign export to csv and Excel - I need export use valueFormatter for some column.

Export working fine, but after I run export to xml, and then run export to Excel - I get xml file.

It's happen only here - because I use getContextMenuItems. Other tables uses standard context menu working fine.

menu:

```
getContextMenuItems = (() => {
const self = this;
return (param) => {
  const menu = [
    'copy',
    'copyWithHeaders',
    'paste',
    'separator',
    {
      name: 'Export',
      subMenu: [
        {
          name: 'csvExport',
          action: () => {
            self.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv({
              processCellCallback: (params) => {
                if (params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter) {
                  const valueFormatterParams: ValueFormatterParams = {
                    ...params,
                    data: params.node.data,
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-non-null-assertion
                    node: params.node!,
                    colDef: params.column.getColDef()
                  };
                  return params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter(valueFormatterParams);
                }
                return params.value;
              },
            });
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'excelExport',
          action: () => {
            self.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
              processCellCallback: (params) => {
                if (params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter) {
                  const valueFormatterParams: ValueFormatterParams = {
                    ...params,
                    data: params.node.data,
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-non-null-assertion
                    node: params.node!,
                    colDef: params.column.getColDef()
                  };
                  return params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter(valueFormatterParams);
                }
                return params.value;
              },
            });
          }
        },
        'excelXmlExport'
      ]
    }
  ];
  return menu;
};
})();
```

Plunker for example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ysaS5IJzOwvVacRb

1. run export to Excel (formated) - get xlsx
2. run export to xml - get xml
3. run export to Excel (formated) - get xml instead xlsx

Answer (score 2):

In your customized Excel Export you got to define `exportMode` property. the reason for explicitly defining this property is that AG Grid uses the same method to export both types and `exportMode` plays a crucial part here. if no export mode is defined then AG Grid uses `this.getExportMode()` which gives last used `exportMode` (in your case XML).

this is how AG Grid has implemented Export functionality.

```
    case 'excelExport':
      return {
       name: localeTextFunc('excelExport', 'Excel Export (.xlsx)&lrm;'),
                action: function () { return _this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
                    exportMode: 'xlsx'
                }); }
            };
        case 'excelXmlExport':
            return {
                name: localeTextFunc('excelXmlExport', 'Excel Export (.xml)&lrm;'),
                action: function () { return _this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
                    exportMode: 'xml'
                }); }
            };
```

Change your code to this and it should work,

```
    self.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
          exportMode: 'xlsx',
          processCellCallback: (params) => {
            if (params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter) {
              const valueFormatterParams: ValueFormatterParams = {
                ...params,
                data: params.node.data,
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-non-null-assertion
                node: params.node!,
                colDef: params.column.getColDef()
              };
              return params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter(valueFormatterParams);
            }
            return params.value;
          },
        });
```

Comment: AG Grid no longer supports "exportMode".  Bummer.